# Cannot construct instance of `java.security.Timestamp` Error in spring Rest

Tags: json, spring, jackson, timestamp, spring-rest

I have a simple Rest controller as follow :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/DepositBalance")
public DepositBalanceResponse DepositBalance(@Valid @RequestBody DepositBalanceRequest requestDto) throws Exception {
    return depositService.GetDepositBalance(requestDto);
}
```

Here is the DepositBalanceRequest fields :

```
private String profileId;
private String userName;
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private Timestamp timestamp;
```

When I invoke the service via Postman like this :

```
{
    "profileId":"asdfasdf",
    "userName":"username",
    "timestamp":"2018-12-30 20:12:20",
}
```

I get the following error :

```
"Type definition error: [simple type, class java.security.Timestamp]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.security.Timestamp` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2018-12-30 20:12:20')\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 14] (through reference chain: com.api.v1.deposit.DepositBalanceRequest[\"timestamp\"])"
```

I'm wondering do I miss something?

Comment: You probably want to use a Java Time version of that, like `LocalDateTime` or `DateTime` instead of the `java.security` or `javax.sql` one.

Comment: `@M.Deinum Thanks, LocalDateTime worked

Comment: Ran into a similar exception after upgrading some legacy code to Java 16. Using `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.security.Timestamp` did the trick for me. But yes, upgrading to the Java 8+ DateTime API is a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to M.Deinum,
It's required to use LocalDateTime instead of Timestamp

```
private String profileId;
private String userName;
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime timestamp;
```